# SL4JF in Tomcat not showing up in log files

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6, slf4j, java.util.logging

I have installed Tomcat, and using SLF4J as our logging framework. I copied `slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar` and `slf4j-jdk14-1.6.4.jar` into the Tomcat library i.e `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`.

I assumed that if I use SLF4J, it shall delegate to `java.util.Logger`, which will delegate to underlying Tomcat logging framework. But when I deploy and check my application, I don't see anything getting logged. All my exception/log information is getting lost.

Is my understanding right, or did I miss anything to keep in class-path?

Comment: Your configuration seems correct to me, please add your JUL configuration file (logging.properties).

Comment: You can see https://github.com/grgrzybek/tomcat-slf4j-logback for a project that replaces Tomcat JULI with pure SLF4J+Logback which doesn't conflict with individual WARs logging configuration

Comment: foch, I use the default logging.properties which gets shipped with the server installation.

      
Grzegorz Grzybek, thanks for the link. but i want to know why by defalt its not working. this means SL4J is not useful if we are using tomcat?

Comment: @Surya: Tomcat (since version 6.0) *uses a private package-renamed implementation of Apache Commons Logging* ([see this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html)). It just doesn't know how to use SLF4J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copying the slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar and slf4j-jdk14-1.6.4.jar under $TOMCAT/lib, i shipped these jars with the war application. in this case my exceptions are getting logged.

Comment: Which configuration file the was picked up when you ship these jars with the war application?
This is totally different from what you asked initially.

Comment: @Surya, many many thanks for the question and answer. Recently, I just started using TomEE 1.5.1 (tomcat 7.0.32+), and I was trying to get my exceptions and logs out to catalina log file while running TomEE as Windows service (via tomcat7 windows service), and I searched and searched this topic for hours, and this answer finally helped me. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is to add the system property to the your CATALINA_OPTS.

For Windows systems, add to your %CATALINA_HOME\bin\catalina.bat file:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=\PATH\TO\YOUR\logging.properties
```

or on Linux/UNIX systems, add to your $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh file:

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/PATH/TO/YOUR/logging.properties
```

Don't forget that in Linux/UNIX systems, you need to quote if you have more than one parameters in the CATALINA_OPTS, e.g.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx256m -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/PATH/TO/YOUR/logging.properties"
```

This line is to ensure that your logging.properties file is being loaded when Tomcat is started.

Comment: I can see log file filled when an exception is thrown from my application. but when i try to log explicitly its failing. also when i checked the catalina.sh, i can see that logging.properties is being set to the correct properties file

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Tomcat to use log4j as described [in its docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j), put log4j.properties to $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory and use slf4j-api with slf4j-log4j12 bridge. So you've got clean slf4j API and log4j goodness like [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) etc.

Comment: the question is about "java.util.Logger" - the default logging for tomcat and not about log4j.